# how to check data according to a column in sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

| finacialscheduletype | finacialscheduletypevalue |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 05/06/2022 |
| 2 | 05/04/2022 |
| 2 | 05/07/2022 |
| 2 | 05/17/2022 |
| 0 | PROJECTED |
| 2 | 05/13/2022 |
| 2 | 03/05/2011 |

i have this table i want to select data

firstly if **financialscheduletype = 2 is there in table** then
firstly query must check wether
**financialscheduletype = 2 is there in table or not then**

**select * from table where financialscheduletype=2** query should run

else

**select * from table where financialscheduletype=0** query should run

Comment: Did you try using OR.

Comment: select financingscheduletype , financingscheduletypevalue
from financingschedule where opid = 'a3718524-96e3-47a1-a3d9-879df86f0911' and 
((financingscheduletype='2' and not financingscheduletype='0')
OR (not financingscheduletype='2' and financingscheduletype='0')) i am trying this but it is showing all data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` in the `where` clause.

Query -

```
select * from finance
where finacialscheduletype = 
case when (select count(*) from finance where finacialscheduletype = 2) > 0 then 2 else 0 end;
```

DB-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dxTSW6q9hFjxm7kPUtpgRo/0).

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is not clear and you don't explain it. You might be describing this:

```
select * from finance
where financialscheduletype=2 or  financialscheduletype=0;
```

which is same as:

```
select * from finance
where financialscheduletype in (2, 0);
```

Or you might be describing this:

```
select * from finance
where financialscheduletype = case 
       when exists (
        select * from myTable 
        where financialscheduletype = 2) then 2 else 0 end;
```